# Oracle changing password, where old password contain @-signs

Tags: database, oracle, change-password

Let say i have a password name **T@mp**

I want to change it to **Hello**

but if i use this following query with my user it wont compile as my old password contain @-signs

```
alter user MYUSER identified by Hello replace T@mp
```

I am using TOAD

[image]

I am changing my password to normal character because,  @-signs also creating problem in SQL loader

```
sqlldr myuser/T@mp@prodcms control=loading.ctl
```

Comment: Try `alter user MYUSER identified by Hello replace "T@mp"`, resp. `sqlldr myuser/"T@mp"@prodcms control=loading.ctl`

Comment: It's working, thank you for your response, please make your comment as  an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @Wernfried Domscheit has shown, you have to enclose the old password in double quotes as shown below.

```
SQL> alter user sales_hr identified by password replace p@assword;
alter user sales_hr identified by password replace p@assword
                                                        *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00922: missing or invalid option


SQL> alter user sales_hr identified by password replace "p@ssword";

User altered.
```